# Is it possible to use glossary recursively?

Tags: glossaries

In the acronym list, I use defintions, like

```
\newacronym{DRAM}{DRAM}{Dynamic \gls{RAM}}
    \newacronym{RAM}{RAM}{Random Access Memory}
```

Where in the text I use first time `\gls{DRAM}`, it appears
`"Dynamic Random Access Memory (RAM) (DRAM)"`, which is correct,
but I feel it somewhat strange, because of the two tags in ellipses.
I understand that it is the first occurrence of `\gls{RAM}`, too,
but I would prefer `"Dynamic Random Access Memory (DRAM)"` only.
Could it be reached using simple means?

Comment: What functionality do you want?  In particular what should `\gls{DRAM} \gls{RAM}` and `\gls{RAM} \gls{DRAM}` produce on first use?

Comment: If you want to do this, it's better to use the extension package `glossaries-extra`, but see [Nested Links](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested) for warnings and limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use nested glossaries all the time, but to avoid problems I use multiple `makeindex` calls (if I use more than one back-traceable level of nested referencing i.e. `\newglossaryentry{A}` contains `\gls{B}` which also refers to `\gls{C}` and A is the term used in the text, not B)

But what your doing is more similar to a dependency where you want to avoid to much first use replication.  To avoid this, I define my entries as known dependencies of each other that an unset the parent term, preventing it from being used for example:

```
\newglossaryentry{DRAM}{%
    type={acronym},
    category={acronym},
    name={DRAM},
    short={DRAM},
    long={Dynamic Random Access Memory},
    description={Dynamic Random Access Memory},
    first={\ifglsused{RAM}
        {Dynamic RAM (DRAM)} % this is the alternative if the parent is used first and it doesn't have to be a gls command
        {\glsunset{RAM}Dynamic Random Access Memory (DRAM)}},
    sort={Dynamic Random Access Memory}
}%
```

which will work with:

```
\newglossaryentry{RAM}{%
    type={acronym},
    category={acronym},
    name={RAM},
    short={RAM},
    long={Random Access Memory},
    description={Random Access Memory},
    first={Random Access Memory (RAM)},
    sort={Random Access Memory}
}%
```